# MS Access: two linked combo boxes on a form

Tags: ms-access

I have three linked dimensions (say color, type, and size of an animal) linked by a fact table.

I would like to create a form with these three dimension choices in combo boxes, so when I select one for a new record, the other two combo boxes refresh with only available values.

For instance, if I select a dog as a type, the color would show (white, black, orange) but not green, if I select size small, the type will not include a whale, etc.

I know i can do in VBA but would like ideally to avoid writing code for this.

Comment: No way without using some VBA if you want real control over it. It's not hard. See the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes referred to as known as Cascading combo boxes, have a read here for one technique http://www.baldyweb.com/CascadingCombo.htm

Comment: Here is a problem. My form display multiple rows(records). Every time I change the source combo box for one records, the dependent combo boxes for all the records change. I need it only to change for the record I am editing now.

Comment: I guess you are using a continuous form, therefore unbound controls won't work as you have discovered. You can put the combo's in the form header and only update the one record selected in the detail section.